# Finding depth of tree haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, depth

I want to find the depth of an `STree` but in my code it won't count the first level.

```
data STree = SNode Label [STree] deriving (Eq,Show)

tdepth :: STree -> Label
tdepth (SNode _ [])= 0
tdepth (SNode l s) = 1 + naiveSumList([tdepth t | t <- s])

naiveSumList :: [Int] -> Label
naiveSumList (x:xs) = x + (naiveSumList xs)
naiveSumList [] = 0
```

`tdepth SNode _ []` must give 1 but how can I count the levels? Here are the `STree`s I've been testing with:

```
s1 = SNode 1 []
s2 = SNode 1 [
        SNode 2 [],
        SNode 3 []
        ]
s3 = SNode 1 [
        SNode 2 [
            SNode 4 [],
            SNode 5 [],
            SNode 6 []
            ],
        SNode 3 []
        ]
s4 = SNode 1 [
        SNode 2 [
            SNode 4 [],
            SNode 5 [
                SNode 7 []
                ],
            SNode 6 []
            ],
        SNode 3 []
        ]
```

My results with code example:

```
tdepth s1  = 0
tdepth s2  = 1
tdepth s3  = 2
tdepth s4  = 3
```

And results should be:

```
 tdepth s1  = 1
 tdepth s2  = 2
 tdepth s3  = 3
 tdepth s4  = 4
```

Comment: Please reword your question. It is not clear, which code you are referring to, you have two different implementations of `tdepth` in the question.

Comment: ok i deleted another

Comment: If you're trying to find the depth of your tree, why are you summing up the depth of each sub-branch?  Shouldn't you be taking the `maximum` of that list?  Also, why use `naiveSumList` when `sum` already exists in `Prelude`?

Comment: @bheklilr because im new by haskell and i dont know prelude too. Trees are really complicated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with the base case.  You want `tdepth (SNode label [])` to return `1`, so let's write that case:

```
tdepth :: STree -> Int
tdepth (SNode _ []) = 1
```

Now we need to know how to compute the depth of a tree.  The depth of a tree is the number of nodes on the longest branch, and your examples of what you expect out of your function are precisely what we're looking for.  Since we're looking for the longest branch, we should be finding the maximum of the depth of each branch.  Luckily, `Prelude` already has a `maximum :: Ord a => [a] -> a` function built in, so we can do

```
tdepth (SNode _ branches) = 1 + maximum [tdepth branch | branch <- branches]
```

Or equivalently (and the version I prefer)

```
tdepth (SNode _ branches) = 1 + maximum (map tdepth branches)
```

However, I don't like the parentheses around `map tdepth branches`, and since we're working with `Int` we can use the `succ` function that simply adds 1 to whatever `Int` is passed to it:

```
tdepth (SNode _ branches) = succ $ maximum $ map tdepth branches
```

But you can use whatever version you like, all three are pretty much equivalent.

All together we now have

```
tdepth :: STree -> Int
tdepth (SNode _ []) = 1
tdepth (SNode _ branches) = 1 + maximum (map tdepth branches)
```

I do have one more problem with this, we've repeated our logic for the depth of a single node, is there any way we can reduce this problem to where we [Don't Repeat Ourselves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)?  If instead of checking for the base case, we figure out a way to make `maximum` return `0` if `branches == []`, then our function wouldn't need two statements.  Unfortunately, `maximum` currently errors if passed an empty list, but we can work around this pretty simply.  All we have to do is ensure that the list passed to `maximum` always has at least one element in it:

```
tdepth :: STree -> Int
tdepth (SNode _ branches) = 1 + maximum (0 : map tdepth branches)
-- Or if you prefer
--                        = succ $ maximum $ 0 : map tdepth branches
```

We can safely prepend `0` onto our depths because we know our depth will always be greater than 0, so calling `maximum` on that list will return a valid result.  Now we have a single expression that will calculate the depth of a tree accurately without having to handle any special cases.